# Very strange SQL Server query behaviour

Tags: sql-server, if-statement

I have a very strange issue with a SQL query.

```
IF NOT EXISTS ([special query here])
    BEGIN
        SELECT 1;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 2;
    END
```

The query above outputs: 2.

However when I replace the `SELECT 1;` part with a large query containing create tables etc. multiple errors are thrown. How is it possible that SQL Server executes code inside the case of an `IF` statement while that case is not true?

Comment: It checks what is in the IF

Comment: Something probably is going wrong in the "large query." Care to share it?

Comment: are you changing the table schema at all in the script? You're question needs more detail.

Comment: The IF NOT EXISTS checks for the existance of a table. The 'large' query is an update script which creates that table and inserts records. It is provided with the software. I'm unable to share it...

Comment: What you have is not a "query" it is a chunk of t-sql containing two queries.  The error is not occurring during execution of either of the 2 queries, but during compilation of the entire chunk of t-sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are changing schema, the parser will look to see that all the entities exist before running it.

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD aNewColumn INT 

UPDATE myTable SET aNewColumn = 0
```

This will produce an error.

You can use dynamic sql, as long as you aren't taking in parameters from a client.

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE myTable SET aNewColumn = 0'
```

Comment: as long as you aren't taking user input, there shouldn't be a `SQL INJECTION` vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors are syntax errors, whether you're in a conditional branch that'll run or a conditional branch that won't run. Parsing occurs before execution, and *must* be successful.

Consider this analogous example written in C++:

```cpp
int main()
{
   if (false) {
       acbukasygdfukasygdaskuygdfas#@4r9837y214r
   }
}
```

You can't write that nonsense line even though it's inside of a block that'll never run, because the program's intended meaning cannot be determined by the compiler.

Comment: I would expect that SQL Management studio would notify any compilation errors as it provides intellisense.